# How to Find the Huang-Rhys factor from the Intensity Vs Wavelength plot (PL plot)?

Tags: physical-properties-of-materials, spectroscopy, photoluminescence

How can I find the HR factor like we calculate the Debye waller factor as - log(IZpl/Itotal), from the intensity profile of the PL spectra.

Comment: Is the PL spectrum obtained from experiment or computation?

Comment: @wzkchem5 in the absence of more information, I'd write an answer based on it literally being a PL spectrum (from a PL experiment). I guess the OP needs to fit a spectral density model containing the HR factor, to best reproduce the PL spectrum, so the HR factor would be obtained from fitting. You probably know better than me though!

Comment: Pl spectra is obtained from an experiment and also HR factor is no a fitting parameter